# What's mean "Result contains obtained parameters: b" in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

Consider the following code fragment:

```
lemma ejercicio_10_MSV2:
  fixes P Q :: "'b ⇒ bool"
  assumes "P a ⟶ (∃x. Q x)"
    shows "∃x. P a ⟶ Q x"
proof -
  { assume "P a"
    with assms have "∃x. Q x" by (rule mp)
    then obtain b where "Q b" by (rule exE)}
```

The invocation of the command `}` is giving the following error: `Result contains obtained parameters: b`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to export the variable b out of its natural scope. Your approach looks wrong and I suggest that you try case analysis on “P a”.

Comment: It's true, thanks!!!